# Caracteres repetidos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Tengo que resolver un ejercicio de Javascript y me he quedado estancada, llevo días dandole vueltas y no soy capaz de acabarlo.
Se trata de: Desarrolla una función en la que se pida al usuario que ingrese una frase y la web responda con la cantidad de caracteres que se han escrito y las veces que se repite cada uno de los que forman la frase.

El código hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
var pregunta = prompt("¿Con qué elemento se juega al         tenis?");
var respuesta = "Raqueta";
var respuesta2 = "raqueta";

if (pregunta == respuesta) {
 alert("Respuesta correcta");
}
else if (pregunta == respuesta2) {
 alert("Respuesta correcta");
}
else {
 alert("Respuesta incorrecta");
}

var respuesta = pregunta.split("").sort();
while (respuesta.lenght > 0) {
 alert(respuesta[0]);
}

console.log(respuesta);
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tu código no tiene absolutamente ninguna relación con el enunciado que has señalado

Comment: Del enunciado que nos das, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?...

Comment: @FrancescoVirgolini _La herramienta que mencionás_ solo sirve **si sabés lo que estás haciendo**. No es la panacea :)

Answer (score -2):

La linea de tu código que se parece a lo que preguntas es:

```
var respuesta = pregunta.split("").sort();
```

Que convierte el texto en un array de caracteres, y luego lo ordena.
Por ejemplo, convierte `"polo"` en `["p","o","l","o"]` y lo ordena `["o","o","p","l"]`
Una vez obtienes el array puedes saber su tamaño con la propiedad length (también directamente con el texto sin convertir).

```
respuesta.length
```

Como lo tienes ordenado, puedes contar los caracteres repetidos fácilmente, ya que estos estarán consecutivos. Puedes almacenar las repeticiones en un nuevo array de objetos donde indiques el carácter y las veces que se repite.

```js
var frase = "Hola que tal, como estas?";
console.log("La frase contiene "+frase.length+" caracteres");
var respuesta = frase.split("").sort();

var repeticiones=[];
var contador = 1;
for (let i=0 ; i < respuesta.length ; i++){
  if (respuesta[i]==respuesta[i+1]) contador++;
  else {
    repeticiones.push({caracter:respuesta[i], repeticiones:contador});
    contador = 1;
  }
}
console.log ("La frase contiene "+repeticiones.length+" caracteres diferentes.");
console.log (repeticiones);
```

En caso que la pregunta no sea cuantos caracteres tiene la frase, si no cuantos caracteres DIFERENTES tiene la frase, solo hace falta mirar `repeticiones.length`

Answer (score -3):

Esto es mas para "Marce Puente" que para responder a la pregunta.

No soy un profesional de programación ni tengo estudios pero lo tengo como hobby.

¿ Por que no has corregido lo de respuesta1 y respuesta2 con un toLowerCase() por ejemplo ?¿ Es correcto hacerlo tan repetitivo ?

y también me ha entrado curiosidad por pensar en diferentes formas de hacer lo que pide y quisiera saber si se te ocurre alguna forma que tenga mas rendimiento en texto grande (he copiado un texto de la documentación de php como ejemplo, baja al final del todo para ver el código funcional).

Por lo que he visto hacer un split.sort es muy lento para contar en comparación con otras opciones (replaceAll me ha sorprendido, lo esperaba más lento).

## Edito

He cambiado la parte útil al principio y el texto de prueba al final, también he añadido otra forma de hacerlo con replaceAll que me ha sorprendido, lo esperaba más lento.

```js
var caracter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
function contar(){

    
    console.time("Prueba 1"); // Split -> Sort -> Splice
    p1 = prueba1();
    console.timeEnd("Prueba 1");
    console.log("Cantidad de A -> ", p1["A"])

    console.time("Prueba 2"); // While
    p2 = prueba2();
    console.timeEnd("Prueba 2");
    console.log("Cantidad de A -> ", p2["A"])

    console.time("Prueba 3"); // ReplaceAll
    p3 = prueba3();
    console.timeEnd("Prueba 3");
    console.log("Cantidad de A -> ", p3["A"])

}

function prueba1(){
    obj = {};
    console.time("Sort Time");
    b = texto.split("").sort();
    console.timeEnd("Sort Time");

    while (b.length  > 0){
        c = b.splice(0,b.lastIndexOf(b[0])+1);
        obj[c[0]] = c.length;
    }
    return obj;
}

function prueba2(){
    i = 0;
    obj = {};
    while (texto.length  > i){
        if(typeof obj[texto[i]] == "undefined"){
            obj[texto[i]] = 1;
        }else{
            obj[texto[i]]++;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return obj;
}

function prueba3(){
    a = texto;
    l_ini = texto.length;
    obj = {}
    for(i = 0; i < caracter.length; ++i){
        a = a.replaceAll(caracter[i], "");
        l_end = a.length;

        if(l_end != l_ini){
            obj[caracter[i]] = l_ini - l_end;
            l_ini = l_end;
        }
        
        
    }
    return obj;
}



            //-----------Ignorar a partir de aqui, esto es el texto grande
texto = `BasicsVariablesinPHParerepresentedbyadollarsignfollowedbythenameofthevariableThevariablenameisc
asesensitiveVariablenamesfollowthesamerulesasotherlabelsinPHPAvalidvariablenamestartswithaletterorundersc
orefollowedbyanynumberoflettersnumbersorunderscoresAsaregularexpressionitwouldbeexpressedthusazAZazAZ09N
oteForourpurposesherealetterisazAZandthebytesfrom128through2550x800xffNotethisisaspecialvariablethatcant
beassignedPriortoPHP710indirectassignmentegbyusingvariablevariableswaspossibleTipSeealsotheUserlandNamin
gGuideForinformationonvariablerelatedfunctionsseetheVariableFunctionsReferencephpvarBobVarJoeechovarVaro
utputsBobJoe4sitenotyetinvalidstartswithanumber4sitenotyetvalidstartswithanunderscoretytemansikkavalidis
ExtendedASCII228BydefaultvariablesarealwaysassignedbyvalueThatistosaywhenyouassignanexpressiontoavariable
theentirevalueoftheoriginalexpressioniscopiedintothedestinationvariableThismeansforinstancethatafterassig
ningonevariablesvaluetoanotherchangingoneofthosevariableswillhavenoeffectontheotherFormoreinformationonth
iskindofassignmentseethechapteronExpressionsPHPalsooffersanotherwaytoassignvaluestovariablesassignbyrefer
enceThismeansthatthenewvariablesimplyreferencesinotherwordsbecomesanaliasfororpointstotheoriginalvariable
ChangestothenewvariableaffecttheoriginalandviceversaToassignbyreferencesimplyprependanampersandtothebegin
ningofthevariablewhichisbeingassignedthesourcevariableForinstancethefollowingcodesnippetoutputsMynameisBo
btwicephpfooBobAssignthevalueBobtofoobarfooReferencefooviabarbarMynameisbarAlterbarechobarechofoofooisalt
eredtooOneimportantthingtonoteisthatonlynamedvariablesmaybeassignedbyreferencephpfoo25barfooThisisavalida
ssignmentbar247Invalidreferencesanunnamedexpressionfunctiontestreturn25bartestInvalidItisnotnecessarytoin
itializevariablesinPHPhoweveritisaverygoodpracticeUninitializedvariableshaveadefaultvalueoftheirtypedepen
dingonthecontextinwhichtheyareusedbooleansdefaulttofalseintegersandfloatsdefaulttozerostringsegusedinecho
aresetasanemptystringandarraysbecometoanemptyarrayExample1DefaultvaluesofuninitializedvariablesphpUnsetAN
DunreferencednousecontextvariableoutputsNULLvardumpunsetvarBooleanusageoutputsfalseSeeternaryoperatorsfor
moreonthissyntaxechounsetbooltruefalseStringusageoutputsstring3abcunsetstrabcvardumpunsetstrIntegerusageo
utputsint25unsetint2502525vardumpunsetintFloatusageoutputsfloat125unsetfloat125vardumpunsetfloatArrayusag
eoutputsarray13string3defunsetarr3defarrayarray3defarray3defvardumpunsetarrObjectusagecreatesnewstdClasso
bjectseehttpwwwphpnetmanualenreservedclassesphpOutputsobjectstdClass11foostring3barunsetobjfoobarvardumpu
nsetobjRelyingonthedefaultvalueofanuninitializedvariableisproblematicinthecaseofincludingonefileintoanoth
erwhichusesthesamevariablenameEWARNINGpriortoPHP800ENOTICElevelerrorisissuedincaseofworkingwithuninitiali
zedvariableshowevernotinthecaseofappendingelementstotheuninitializedarrayissetlanguageconstructcanbeusedt
odetectifavariablehasbeenalreadyinitializedaddanoteUserContributedNotes5notesupdown69jeffdotphpnetattanas
itydotcom12yearsagoThispageshouldincludeanoteonvariablelifecycleBeforeavariableisusedithasnoexistenceItis
unsetItispossibletocheckifavariabledoesntexistbyusingissetThisreturnstrueprovidedthevariableexistsandisnt
settonullWiththeexceptionofnullthevalueavariableholdsplaysnopartindeterminingwhetheravariableissetSetting
anexistingvariabletonullisawayofunsettingavariableAnotherwayisvariablesmaybedestroyedbyusingtheunsetconst
ructphpprintissetaaisnotsetPrintsfalseOrmoreaccuratelyprintsb0issetbreturnstrueormoreaccurately1carrayiss
etcreturnstruebnullNowissetbreturnsfalseunsetcNowissetcreturnsfalseisnullisanequivalenttesttocheckingthat
issetisfalseThefirsttimethatavariableisusedinascopeitsautomaticallycreatedAfterthisissetistrueAtthepointa
twhichitiscreateditalsoreceivesatypeaccordingtothecontextphpabooltrueabooleanastrfooastringIfitisusedwith
outhavingbeengivenavaluethenitisuninitalizedanditreceivesthedefaultvalueforthetypeThedefaultvaluesarethee
mptyvaluesEgBooleansdefaulttoFALSEintegersandfloatsdefaulttozerostringstotheemptystringarraystotheemptyar
rayAvariablecanbetestedforemptinessusingemptyphpa0ThisissetbutisemptyUnsetvariablesarealsoemptyphpemptyve
sselreturnstrueAlsovesselisunsetEverythingaboveappliestoarrayelementstoophpitemarrayNowissetitemreturnstr
ueButissetitemunicornisfalseemptyitemistrueandsoisemptyitemunicornitemunicornNowissetitemunicornistrueAnd
emptyitemisfalseButemptyitemunicornisstilltrueitemunicornPinkunicornissetitemunicornisstilltrueAndemptyit
emisstillfalseButnowemptyitemunicornisfalseForarraysthisisimportantbecauseaccessinganonexistentarrayitemc
antriggererrorsyoumaywanttotestarraysandarrayitemsforexistencewithissetbeforeusingthemupdown16anisgazigat
gmaildotcom2yearsagoclearconceptofvariabledeclarationrulesandclassificationvariabledeclarationrules1start
withdollarsign2firstletterofvariablenamecomesfromazAz3nextlettersofvariablenamecomesfromazAZ094nospacenos
yntexclassificationofvariablesVariablearemainlyTwotypes1PredefinedVariable2UserDefineVariablePredefinedVa
riableThereare12predefinedvariablesinphp81GLOBALS2SERVER3REQUEST4FILES5ENV6SESSION7COOKIE8GET9POST10httpr
esponseheader11argc12argvUserDefineVariableUserDefinevariableare3types1variablescope2variablevariables3re
ferencevariableVariableScopevariablescopeare3types1localscope2globalscope3staticvariableupdown8anisgaziga
tgmaildotcom2yearsagothisisaspecialvariablesowecannotassignitButPriortoPHP710indirectassignmentsuchasvari
ablevariablesareallowedbdthisbdCountryNickNameechothisallowedpriortoPHP710butfromtheversionof710itwasallo
wedupdown6anisgazigatgmaildotcom1yearagothisisaspecialvariablesowecannotassignitButbeforePHP710indirectas
signmentssuchasvariablevariablesareallowedbdthisbdCountryNickNameechothisallowedpriortoPHP710butfromtheve
rsionof710itwasnotallowedandthrowafatalerrorupdown26Anonymous6yearsagoIhighlyrecommendtouseaneditorthatca
nlistallvariablenamesinaseparatewindowThereasonaretypingerrorsinvariablenamesphpsomenamenobodyNowwewantto
usesomenamesomewhereechosomemaneAndwonderwhyitdoesntprintnobodyThereasonissimplewehaveatypingerrorinsomen
ameandsomemaneisanewvariableInthisexampleitmightbeeasytofindButifyouusevariablestocalculatesomethingsyoum
ighthardlyfinditandaskyourselfwhyyourcalculationisalwayswrongWithaneditorthatlistallvariablenamesinasepar
atewindowsuchdoublevariablesbutwithwrongtypingcanbeeasilyfoundBTWItwouldhavebeenbetterifthePHPlanguagewou
ldrequiretousesomesortofkeywordtodefineavariablethefirsttime`
            

contar();
```

Comment: porque pones un curso de php en tu respuesta si nada tiene que ver con la pregunta que por cierto, esta mal formulada?

Comment: Primero que nada, me encanta ver gente con la programación como hobby esforzándose por hacer las cosas lo más óptimas posible... pero ni esto es una pregunta correcta (el enunciado y el código son completamente diferentes y aquí no hacemos los deberes a nadie), ni me parece correcto intentar responder de la manera más óptima posible a un usuario que obviamente tiene un ejercicio para empezar a aprender a programar. Tú crees que tu código es comprensible por alguien que lleva dos semanas estudiando? La respuesta debe ser adecuada a la pregunta, no sirve que copien sin más, deben entenderla.

Comment: infinit3Loop__ como he dicho solo es un texto grande para hacer la prueba

Comment: Benito-B en un principio estaba comentando la respuesta de Marce Puente pero se me alargo demasiado, a partir de la pregunta está me ha surgido una duda y entre que está relacionado con la pregunta y que ya hay alguien con bastante reputación que ha respondido quise saber más, ya se que no se hacen los deberes de nadie por eso no he usado nada suyo, si entiende mi código perfecto por e,l ya tiene una solución a su pregunta, lo deje claro en lo primero que dije.

Comment: @AntonioTorres oh... disculpa

Comment: Hola Antonio, primero, para que el otro usuario sea notificado de tu mención, debes usar **@nombreUsuario**, hoy llegué aquí por casualidad, y vi tu comentario, tienes razón, se puede mejorar como indicas, en general, trato de tocar el código del OP, lo menos posible, tal vez sea un error, en cuanto a la optimización, si lees la pregunta, verás que hay dos "cosas" distintas, la pregunta que plantea el texto y un código que nada tiene que ver con esta.

Comment: en el sitio, está mal visto (en algunos casos, comparto postura) responder preguntas que no presentan ningún intento, por parte del OP, por lo que solo me limité, a hacer correcciones sobre el código mostrado, no respondí la pregunta del texto, ahora bien, salvo que la pregunta sea explícitamente sobre optimización, no lo tenemos en cuenta, ya que haría que responder, sea una odisea, valoro que lo hayas hecho, porque yo no lo haría, gracias por estar atento.

Answer (score -5):

Es difícil saber que necesitas, partiendo de tu pregunta, que no tiene nada que ver con el código que nos muestras, pero bue... veamos los errores de tu código.

```
   // no se si es lo que necesitas, esta linea crea un array con las letras de la  
   // respuesta, y después lo ordena  , esto hará que si la respuesta es
   // "Raqueta" el while mostrará las letras "R", "a",  "a", "e", "q", "t", "u" 
var respuesta = pregunta.split("").sort();

   // por suerte equivocaste el nombre de la propiedad "length", por eso no se entra  
   // en el "while", digo por suerte, porque la condición del mismo, es que la  
   // longitud del "array" sea mayor que "0", cosa que siempre será, por lo que  
   // tendrías un hermoso bucle infinito
while( respuesta.lenght > 0 ) {

   // aquí hay otro problemín, siempre imprimes lo que hay en la primer posición  
    alert( respuesta[ 0 ] );
}
```

Como puedes ver, unas pocas cositas, te separan de la respuesta correcta.
Veamos como quedaría...

```js
  var pregunta = prompt( "¿Con qué elemento se juega al tenis?" );
  var respuesta = "Raqueta";
  var respuesta2 = "raqueta";

  if( pregunta === respuesta ) {
     alert( "Respuesta correcta" );
  }
  else if( pregunta === respuesta2 ) {
     alert( "Respuesta correcta" );
  } 
  else {
     alert( "Respuesta incorrecta" );
  }

  var respuesta = pregunta.split( "" ).sort();
  
     // creamos una variable que usaremos para determinar el ciclo de vida del "while".  
  let i = 0;

     // condición, que el valor de "i" sea menor que la longitud del array  
  while( i < respuesta.length ) {

        // cambiamos el "0" por "i" para que nos muestre todas las letras
     alert( respuesta[ i ] );

        // incrementamos "i" para generar el estado que nos saca del "while"
     i++;  
  }

  console.log( respuesta );
```